# NSBundle pathForResource:ofType: occasionally returns nil for one resource

Tags: iphone, ios

Usually when trying to load a specific resource in my app via `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"splang"]` it works fine, but every once in awhile nil is returned instead. The iphone.splang file in question is a ~275 KB text file that is definitely bundled with the app (as evidenced by it usually being possible to load).

I have verified that it is pathForResource:ofType: that is returning nil, not the mainBundle method.

Comment: Is anything written to the console when this failure occurs?

Comment: are you 100% positive that it is case-sensitive named the exact same way as the file?

Comment: @user1118321 The only thing relevant written to the console is a log message from an exception I raise due to pathForResource returning nil.

Comment: @snb im assuming you have done a build clean etc?

Comment: Hey @snb, have you made any progress finding the source of this problem? I'm experiencing it too.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem of internazionalization.
According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), pathForResource only returns nil if the file is not found. But it also says:

> The method first looks for a matching resource file in the non-localized resource directory of the specified bundle. [...] If a matching resource file is not found, it then looks in the top level of any available language-specific “.lproj” directories. (The search order for the language-specific directories corresponds to the user’s preferences.) It does not recurse through other subdirectories at any of these locations.

Maybe you're trying your code on diferent machines with different languages or the simulator.

Also, `[NSBundle mainbundle]` can return nil, so performing any call on that would also return nil.

> [...] Be sure to check the return value to make sure you have a valid bundle.

Comment: I explicitly check the return value of `[NSBundle mainbundle]` and haven't seen it return nil yet, so I don't think that's it. I also don't think it's a problem of language-specific directories since the file in question is in the non-localized resource directory. `pathForResource` is just sometimes returning nil on the same device, without making any changes to language settings. `pathForResource` is called on app start-up, and the problem can be triggered eventually by just force quitting and restarting the app repeatedly.